# Exposing an Immutable and Mutable Record Class C#

Tags: c#, immutability, record, mutable

I would like to write a set of c# record classes that offer both a Immutable and Mutable version of themselves.
This is similar to how there is a List and ReadOnlyList offered in c# (yes, arguably not quite as safe as the caller can still cast to the mutable version, but I am okay with that and that is not the heart of my question)

There are a few issues that I am running into in my implementations that I've tried so far:
**Implement with Interfaces**

```
    public record class MutableRecord : IReadOnlyRecord
    {
        public int ValueTypeProperty { get; set; }

        // This is is one problem. In the Mutable Record I would like to expose the Mutable 
        // version of the other record type. As opposed to the readonly interface.

        // public OtherMutableRecord RefernceTypeProperty { get; set; }
        public IReadOnlyRecord RefernceTypeProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IReadOnlyOtherRecord
    {
        int SomeData { get; }
    }

    public record class OtherMutableRecord : IReadOnlyOtherRecord
    {
        public int SomeData { get; set; }
    }
```

**Implementation with Base Classes**
I tried swapping out the above interfaces with base classes and then using the new keyword to achieve implementation hiding. But c# doesn't allow for multiple inheritance. In many cases I have classes which need to derive from the ReadOnlyBase class and the other base class (used for other operations in the code, such as storing common objects in a List). So ideally the interface implementation would be best, but I can't get around the interface requiring a specific type.

Comment: This article should help you clarify the "record" concept: https://www.daveabrock.com/2020/11/02/csharp-9-records-immutable-default/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation) to use expose different properties or levels of access based on the reference type:

```
public record class MutableRecord : IReadOnlyRecord
{
    public int ValueTypeProperty { get; set; }

    IReadOnlyOtherRecord IReadOnlyRecord.RefernceTypeProperty => ReferenceTypeProperty;
    public OtherMutableRecord ReferenceTypeProperty { get;  set;}
}
```

Note that "immutable" and "readonly" means slightly different things. The former implies that the object never changes, while the later that you cannot change it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think this works for my application! Thank you!!!

Comment: Also thank you for the comment about immutability and readonly. I completely agree with the slight difference you point out and it is an important one. I will likley update my class names or something to make the intent more clear to the other developers on my team